# Validating my form with Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm having a bad time trying to figure out how to validate a form that I am submitting with jquery's post function.

All I want to do is to only submit the form if the 'bill_cost' field has been completed. The form works *without* the validation code. I am trying to use  the [jquery live form validation plugin](http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-live-form-validation/) but for some reason its' not working. Please can anyone tell me what's wrong / where I should place the validation code? Thanks.

The form

```
     <form class="form-inline" action="" id="myform" form="" method="post">

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="bill_cost"></label>  
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <input id="bill_cost" name="bill_cost" type="text" placeholder="Bill Cost" class="form-control input-lg" required>

  </div>
</div>


<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit1"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="submitButtonId" name="submit1" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

The Jquery

```
   <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#message").hide();
$("#submitButtonId").on("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

var formdata = $(this.form).serialize();
    $.post('../php_includes/insert.php', formdata,
           function(data){
               $("#message").html(data);
               $("#message").fadeIn(500); 
  $("#message").fadeOut(500); 

                //Validate the form
        jQuery(function(){
                jQuery("#bill_cost").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter the Required field"
                });

                jQuery('.myform').validated(function(){

                });
            });
            //End of validation


//Reset Form
$('#myform')[0].reset(); 
          });
return false;

});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing preventing your form post. Move your post code to your validated function.

Edit - Adding code to show how to validate and then submit.  Also, I added a type="submit" to the button, because the validation code is auto-hooking into the form submission event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#message").hide();

  //Define your validation rules.
  $("#bill_cost").validate({
    expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
    message: "Should be a number"
  });

  //Define the event that will occur when the entire form is validated (on form submission)
  $('#myform').validated(function(){
    var formdata = $('#myform').serialize();

    //Post form data
    $.post('#', formdata, function(data){
      //Process post response
      $("#message").html(data);
      $("#message").fadeIn(500); 
      $("#message").fadeOut(500); 
    });

    //Reset Form
    $('#myform')[0].reset(); 
  });

});
```

Comment: I've simplified and double checked that my form works but I don't where I should put the post code within the validation code. Any more help would be great.

Comment: I made a CodePen for you that is working: http://codepen.io/nobrien/pen/YqeWYw.  It submitting back to the pen, for testing purposes.  Change the path to your submission page for your work.

Comment: That's great. Works just as I hoped. Thaks.

Comment: Any idea why the example in code pen causes the input size to get enlarged each time an error message is shown. I can't see where I can adjust the css of the error message?

Comment: Looks like adding a border when there wasn't one before causing the padding on the input field to be removed (not sure why, I am not a css god :)).  I added a default border and padding to codepen, so it doesn't change when the error border is shown.

Comment: Thanks. I still seem to get the same problem. The input field gets wider and the submit button drops down when the error is displayed. I am in fact using bootstrap so there might be an issue. I guess I'll try and get this into bootply and see of I can find the problem there. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: Here the `validated` event calls the `$.post`, so it only runs when the form validates.

```js
jQuery(function(){
    $("#submitButtonId").on("click",function(e){
          e.preventDefault();

          var formdata = $(this.form).serialize();
          //Validate the form
          jQuery("#bill_cost").validate({
                    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                    message: "Please enter the Required field"
          });

          return false;

    });

    jQuery('.myform').validated(function(){
        $.post('../php_includes/insert.php', formdata, 
             function(data){
             $("#message").html(data);
             $("#message").fadeIn(500); 
             $("#message").fadeOut(500); 

             //Reset Form
             $('#myform')[0].reset(); 
             });
    });
});
```