# How to add a external plugin to Bootply?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootply

Apologies if this is off topic but I am trying to create a bootply to demonstrate a css issue I am having with [this question I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520792/validating-my-form-with-jquery/36520862?noredirect=1#comment60858894_36520862).
I can't seem to be able to load an external plugin into the bootply framework. Here is the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/aqm1dKOOsV), can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you

Comment: Just add it as a script reference to the HTML:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.geektantra.com/projects/jquery-form-validate/javascripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

Comment: I tried this and updated my bootply but still no luck. Can you tell me what I've don wrong?